# NULL error returned from crashing NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to set up a basic `NSFetchedResultsController` and it's throwing a "null" error at me from the error below. Since both the error and its userInfo at null, I have no clue what I can even begin to do to work out what's going wrong. It's one of those 'having your head slammed into a brick wall and not being told why' moments of programming. Here's the part that's causing the crash, which is in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSError *error;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch: &error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error! %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

And here's the method that sets the controller up:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Quote" inManagedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending: YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize: 50];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest managedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath: nil cacheName: @"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]
```

instead of

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]
```

Cause if the `_fetchedResultsController` is not alloced, you won't dispatch the `-fetchedResultsController` method, only you use `self.fetchedResultsController`, the getter method will be dispatched.

Comment: Seems like that got it, thankyou. I'm getting an object cannot be nil error on the array now..

Comment: I'm getting it on this line: `    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest managedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath: nil cacheName: @""];
`

Comment: @lukech Have you retained the managedObjectContext when you alloc the view controller? B.t.w, it is better to ask a new question instead of continuing the comments below the answer. :)

Comment: Retained it? I'm not sure what you mean, I'm using ARC.

Comment: @lukech e.g. `YourViewController * yourViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init...]; yourViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` Here `YourViewController` is the class your `fetchedResultsController` in.

Comment: I've done that inside `AppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, yup.

Comment: @lukech can you create a new question & paste your code about the array? And don't forget to leave the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067842/nsfetchedresultscontroller-seems-to-be-inserting-empty-objects-into-array

Comment: There you go, hope that helps.